# mysql select in list with regexp/substring

Tags: mysql

I have table A:

```
---CODE-----
|21XDS60020| <-There is somewhere in table B
|21XDS60021|
|21XDS60023| <-There is somewhere in table B
|21XDS60025|
|21XDS60026|
```

And table B:

```
----------------DESCRIPTION--------------------------
|FAX21XDS60020[2008_504571][NMS]sdfg bla bla        |
|FAX21XDS52167[2008_XXX324][NMS]sdfg bla blb        |
|FAX21P025P61[2006_501909][21XDS60023]sdfg bla blc  |
|FAX21XDS60025[2006_502499][NMS]sdfg bla bld        |
|FAX21P0251296[2007_503659][NMS]sdfg bla ble        |
```

---

Expected Result:

```
---------------------DESCRIPTION--------------------
|FAX21XDS60020[2008_504571][NMS]sdfg bla bla       |
|FAX21P025P61[2006_501909][21XDS60023]sdfg bla blc |
```

I want to select all 'description' records from table B, if they contain as substring one of the 'code' records of table A
I don't know if I can use somehow IN or EXISTS and REGEXP statements in that case.

Something like (of course the following is wrong) :

```
SELECT description FROM B WHERE description IN (select REGEXP(.*code.*) FROM A);
```

Comment: is CODE and DESCRIPTION a field in table A/B? of Course such a query is possible and May be "ok" in a very small Environment, but separating individual informations would be a Need have for using Indexes to not have a poor Performance of the queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a correlated `EXISTS` something like this:

```
SELECT description FROM B 
WHERE exists (
    select 1 FROM A
    where B.description like concat('%',A.code,'%') 
);
```

Comment: That's great! Many thanks for your **instant** answer mate!

Answer (score 1):

This is a JOIN operation with a nasty [nasty unsargable slow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) `ON` condition.

```
SELECT B.description
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON B.description LIKE CONCAT('%', A.code, '%')
```

It's slow because `'needle' LIKE '%haystack%'` means MySQL has to look at everything in the haystack to find the needle.

On the other hand, `'needle' LIKE 'haystack%'` (without the leading `%`) *can* use an index. So if this works in your data you should use it.

```
SELECT B.description
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON B.description LIKE CONCAT('FAX', A.code, '%')
```